# Local Area Messenger in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, local, area, lan

i've recently started to learn Ruby language. and I've got an idea, I want to build a "Local Area Messenger", it will be a web application like Skype but locally, but I  really don't know where to go, If anyone have any..any idea or "links"....It would be great. thanks in advance...cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Journeta is a dirt simple library for peer discovery and message passing between Ruby applications on a LAN.

http://journeta.rubyforge.org/